# How to install Macbuntu in 12.10?

Tags: installation, 12.10, macbuntu

How to install Macbuntu in Ubuntu 12.10? Currently, there are no updates for Macbuntu. The last update is only for Ubuntu 10.10. Is there any way to install the great Macbuntu in Ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Unity came along in 11.04 the transformation pack which was the basis for Macbuntu is no longer relevant.  Unity has borrowed a lot from the Mac graphical environment and improved on it in some ways.  Give Ubuntu 12.10 a go.

If you decided you just had to have Macbuntu you could always install Gnome 2.6 and the transformation pack.

Comment: how i can install genome 2.6 in quantal???

Answer (score 0):

The method I used was to install Ubuntu 10.10, install Macbuntu, and use system update to Ubuntu 11.04, then update that to 12.10.  This trick is long-winded, but it works!